# Phonegap How to add title to the "select" pop up

Tags: html, select, cordova, title

I'm developping a mobile application with phonegap. In this app, i use "select" elements. When i click on the select to change the option, a pop-up appears (as expected) with the options.

My question is : Is there a way to add a title to this pop-up ? (without plugin)

Thanks

Comment: I don't remember for sure, but you can try <label for="your_select_id">Title of select</label>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `optgroup` wrapper on your options.

Example:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Your Title">
        <option>1</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```